# Can you load a binary resource into a DLL?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, dll

I'm having a problem with Visual Studio 2022. I am using the same exact code

HRSRC myResource = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(), RT_RCDATA);

This exact same function, when used in my .exe solution will build fine, and load binary data I've added as a resource.

When compiled as a dll and run through injection, this function always returns NULL.

The error message is: **The specified resource type cannot be found in the image file.**

Comment: Using an HMODULE of NULL means it's looking in the .exe, not your DLL.

Comment: Can you use the trick of creating a dummy function and doing     GetModuleHandleExW(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS | GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT, (LPCWSTR)Dummy_Function, &hm);
This will return a module for the current DLL, AFAIK. Is that the correct module to use in FindResource?

Comment: Unfortunately it's been a very long time since I had to do this, I don't remember the best way of getting the hModule of your DLL.  I would have left a full answer if I did.

Comment: Alright, thanks anyways, atleast I have a direction to go now. I've tested my hypothesis and it didn't work, if anyone posts the full answer I'll accept it.

Comment: If you are doing the resource loading from within the DLL the best way to get the HMODULE is to save it to a global during DllMain. From outside the DLL you need to save the HMODULE returned from LoadLibrary. Note that HMODULE and HINSTANCE values are interchangeable.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir I'm attempting to save the DllMain HMODULE to a global variable but am getting linking problems. Can I simply declare extern HMODULE myHandle, and in DLLMain make it equal to hModule? I am attempting this but it is not propagating across all files in my project.

Comment: Consider using resource only dll ,then  call  LoadLibraryEx. See document: [Use a resource-only DLL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/creating-a-resource-only-dll?view=msvc-170)

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass HMODULE through dllmain:

```
HMODULE DllHandle1;

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        DllHandle1 = hModule;
    ...
```

Then call module in function.

```
foo(){
     HRSRC rec = ::FindResource(DllHandle1, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(XXX), Resource Types);
        unsigned int recSize = ::SizeofResource(DllHandle1, rec );
        HGLOBAL recData = ::LoadResource(DllHandle1, rec );
        void* recData = ::LockResource(recData);
....
}
```